# What movie (or movie trailer) featured people sliding off a large balcony or skyscraper floor?

Tags: story-identification, trailer

I recall a trailer that I *thought* was for The Amazing Spider-Man, which featured either a high balcony or building floor tilting and people sliding off. Having finally watched The Amazing Spider-Man, I now know that no such event occurs, so I am left wondering what I'm remembering. I would have seen this trailer sometime in the 2000s.

Some more points that I'm less sure about:

- The main character is standing below the building when this occurs. His love interest is up on the balcony or floor, and he is standing with his love interest's father down below.
- The main character has to choose between saving his love interest and stopping the balcony/floor from collapsing, but finds a way to do both (this point makes me wonder if I saw more than just the trailer...).
- The love interest's father is a police officer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [Spider Man 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0413300/) (2007)

You see Gwen Stacey modelling clothes. A crane hits her building and she slides down the floor. All looks lost but at the last minute she's saved by Spider Man. Note that her father is indeed the Chief of Police.

Answer (score 3):

Might be Spiderman 1 with Tobey Maguire. There's a scene where Mary Jane slides down a balcony.